# What is the grammar of this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

> Consequently, children are likely to have less supervision at home than **was common** in the traditional family structure.

Could anyone tell me why **was common** is in this position and what is its meaning?

[Source](http://teachersinstitute.yale.edu/curriculum/units/2000/2/00.02.05.x.html)

Comment: In English, what part of speech is the word **was**? Do you know? Did you look up the adjective **common** in your dictionary?

Comment: children are likely to have less supervision at home than in the traditional family structure **was common**?  I did get the grammar book..But I didn't know where to go...@P.E.Dant

Comment: Again: In English, what part of speech is the word **was**? Do you know?

Comment: Sorry,I don't know..You question is kinda abstractive to me...My English is not as good as you think...@P.E.Dant

Comment: Do you know what a _verb_ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence contrasts *are* with *traditional*, or more clearly, the amount of supervision children are likely to have now (*are*) vs the common (in the sense of *usual*) amount of supervision children had in the past (*traditional*).

The structure is clearer if we fill in some words:

- Consequently, children are likely to have less supervision at home (now) than (the amount of supervision that) was common in the traditional family structure (in the past).

You ask:

> Could anyone tell me why was common is in this position and what is its meaning?

The meaning of "was common" is as described above.

The words "was common" sit naturally where you originally found them. Although the sentence can still be understood if "was common" was moved to the end, that arrangement is uncommon. You can see this more clearly if you change the phrase into a sentence. Compare:

- It was common in the traditional family structure.
- It in the traditional family structure was common.

Both are understandable, but the former 'flows' better.